# Artistic characters?

Tags: translation, usage, characters, meaning-in-context

Came across characters which appear to be written on parchment. Any idea why it’d be framed or the meaning of it? All I can tell is that it seems to be a [poetic] story. (The characters in red are a signature and appear on other paintings as well.)

[image: frame]

(I realize the image is horizontal, but if I were have rotate it some of the characters get cut off.)

Answer (score 3):

the main text is 洛神賦

[https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/洛神賦](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/%E6%B4%9B%E7%A5%9E%E8%B3%A6)

the inscription is the last line (above the seal)

> 同治戊辰閏夏臨于何氏之還讀我書齋

同治戊辰閏夏 is 22nd may - 19th june, in the year of 1868

[image]

臨于何氏之還讀我書齋 means copied (臨摹) at mr. ho (何氏) 's (之) premise that named "還讀我書齋"

well, the seal is unrecognised in this resolution. do you have a higher quality one?

have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for a point in the right direction. Indeed seems to be written (for/to?) Luo Shenfu, the wife of our author’s older brother - Cao Pi. (I changed the image to higher resolution; hope it helps.)

Comment: @oliver, only a third of the seal is shown, in the updated picture :(

Comment: I see what mean; sorry. Changed the image now.

Comment: @Oliver did you really change the image? I still can’t see the seal clearly.

Comment: @droooze I did. Before it was cut off; now it’s full. I regret that it may be unclear though.